# apache http server: rewrite rule: how to make a basedir change?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, rewrite

This page:

```
http://test/subdira/subdirb/
```

has relative links, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="res/ext-base.js"></script>
```

The problem is that the directory `res/` is not in `/subdira/subdirb/` but in another directory (`/js/ext-3.3.1/cm`). So I'm wondering how to change the basedir (or maybe another solution).
So if I try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /js/ext-3.3.1/cm/index.html [QSA,L]
```

I may now be able to call the "base" url without 'subdira/subdirb/
' like this:

```
http://test/
```

but... if I do this, this relative link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="res/ext-base.js"></script>
```

doesn't work anymore because it tries to access the /res/ext-base.js, not the good one.

Any idea how I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it here:

(Section "Search pages in more than one directory")

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html

I've taken the opposite side: test if the file is in the subdirectory, if so, stop and go ahead:

```
RewriteCond         %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/js/ext-3.3.1/cm/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)  /js/ext-3.3.1/cm/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond         %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/js/ext-3.3.1/cm%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)  /js/ext-3.3.1/cm$1 [QSA,L]
```

it works \o/